# How to upload a PHP file on Azure

Tags: php, sql, azure

Right now I have a localhost database using WAMP server.
I connect and insert data to this DB by making a POST request to the file's PHP link (e.g localhost/sensor_data/connect_To_DB_And_Insert_Data.**php**).

I want to do the exact same thing with Azure SQL so my database won't be local anymore but on a remote server.

I have already created a database but I don't know how to upload a PHP file that can be accessed online using a link. There are so many documentations that I'm kind of lost and I didn't find an answer to this yet.

So my question is, how do I upload a PHP file on Azure, that it can be accessed by a link, so I can insert data to the database by making a post request to that link ?

Comment: Have you created an App Service plan? You can use [git](https://git-scm.com/) for this, you can use FTP.. you have a few options. Browse through [their docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/) to look at all the available ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly**, you just need to change the connection string in your PHP code. Then your PHP application will be able to connect to Azure SQL. In this way, you do not need to create any Azure host server (Web app or VM).

You can get the connection string on Azure portal:

[image]

**Attention**, as Azure SQL has enabled firewall. So, if you want to connect to it from your local server, you need to [add your IP to the allowed IP list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#create-and-manage-ip-firewall-rules)

[image]

---

However, as @UkraineInTheMembrane suggested in the comment, you can also to use Azure Web App or VM to host your PHP application.

With Azure Web App, here is a get-started tutorial for PHP:  [Create a PHP web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-php) , in this tutorial, git is used to manage your code.

There are also many other approaches to upload your code to azure web app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip

[image]